# Pass values to function without using parameter in PHP?

Tags: php

How can we pass the variable value to function without using any parameter? Once we run the script variable value can be echo within the function.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What's wrong with parameters?

Comment: The only solution would be to use a global variable, but I don't really see the need for that. Maybe if you expand your question it would be easier to understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You could use the keyword `global`, although I think you shouldn't. 
Example:

```
$a = 'foo';
bar();

function bar(){
    global $a;
    echo $a;
}
```

Above code will print "foo";

Again, I really think you should not use this and come up with some other implementation that doesn't require the use of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of variable by declaring the variable as global variable.